# Does the provisioning profile itself enough for Code signing the app?

Tags: ios, provisioning-profile, ios-provisioning

I am trying to prepare an ad-hoc build for an iOS app. I am registered as a team member(TEAM ROLE) in apple development program. 
My team admin has already generated distribution certificate and have registered device and also generated distribution provisioning profile.

Now I want to know , If I want to create build from my local system, Does the provisioning profile itself is sufficient to make the build or I need to install distribution certificate as well? 
I am curious to know because I think, provisioning profile has all the necessary information like: 
Distribution Certificate and device info 
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you will need both the distribution certificate and the matching provisioning profile installed on the machine doing the build.

If the distribution certificate isn't installed you won't be able to select it from the 'Code signing identity' build setting.

Comment: thanks, this would certainly help! So I need to ask distribution certificate from my admin, (As with team role, i can't directly download it thru apple development portal) . If this is the case, Is there a way exist so that I could check the validity of distribution certificate against the provisioning profile ? I  mean the provisioning profile is correctly linked to same distribution certificate which is provided by admin ! I am asking just because, everytime I am trying to make build and while installing,  I get an alert message <appname> could not be installed at this time !

Comment: Yes, once you have installed the distribution certificate open 'Keychain Access' and check that your certificate has a private key (it should have a little arrow to the left of it which you can click to expand). If it doesn't then you need to find a machine that has the private key and export the certificate which you will then need to install on your machine. If there is no other machine with the private key, i think you will have to revoke the certificate and regenerate it.

Comment: ok, Distribution certificate is installed, but private key is missing.  I guess this must be the issue, thanks a lot for this information.